# what permissions should jenkins have to execute shell-commands without being insecure?

Tags: linux, permissions, jenkins, permission-denied

I have a script (test.sh) on a local server, which works fine when executed in a terminal. The script removes a directory, and recreates a directory local. It then connects to a remote server using "ssh -i $private_key .." and copies a file there.

When I execute this script in jenkins with

```
sh test.sh
```

it doesnt work. I get the following errors:

```
rm: .. Permission denied
mkdir: .. Permission denied
Warning: Identity file /.ssh/private_key not accessible: Permission denied.
```

Jenkins is on the same server as the script.

I see that Jenkins is another user and cant do everything that I'm doing as root; how can I set the permissions without losing all security. Especially in case of the private_key, it would be silly to set the permissions to easy - it is currently set to 600 (read and write permission for the owner) and the owner is root.

Comment: Are you trying to use keys installed to other user's .ssh directory (not the one Jenkins is running under)? This is the wrong bit then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of setting the private key's permissions to 600 is that no other user should be able to access it. If you have placed the keys in another user's home directory (/home/anotheruser/.ssh), then neither the Jenkins user, nor anyone else (except root) will be able to access it. **This is as designed**.

<strike>If you want your Jenkins user to be able to use the private key, copy it over to the jenkins users home directory as well (/home//.ssh).</strike>

Also, if you are trying to delete/create directories in some other user's directory as the Jenkins user without providing permissions, you will get a permissions error. This is because of security. The only way to allow this is the allow the Jenkins user to make changes to those directories.

One safe option is to add the Jenkins user to the same group as the other user. Once you do this, set the permissions on the directories you want to read from and write to, to allow anyone in the user's group to make changes.

```
rwxrwx---
```

The above permissions will allow the owner of the folder and any other users in the same group to make changes, but will not allow anyone else. This is safe, since you control who is part of the other user's group.

**EDIT**

It looks like your error has changed, though. You're not getting permission denied any more. Can you still do it through terminal? The reason (I think) it is saying that the host key verification has failed is because your key was originally created for the other user. I realise I said to do this in the answer above, but it is not the right way.

As the jenkins user, can you run the following commands:

```
ssh-keygen (say yes or agree if it asks if you want to replace your current keys)
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remoteuser@remote_server
ssh remoteuser@remote_server
```

If this works, try your script through the terminal, and then through jenkins again...

Comment: Even if I put the key in Jenkins home directory (in .ssh) and set jenkins as owner, it still does not work. "Host key verification failed.
Host key verification failed.
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
Host key verification failed.
Build step 'Shell ausführen' marked build as failure". I really have no idea where this comes from. So thanks for the assistance and any idea.

Comment: first of all thanks for the assistance. I can still execute the script through terminal (as root). Which user do you mean with "originally created for the other user"? The keys have been generated for a user at the remote server. So I can connect as this user to the remote server, from any server with the private key. If I try to regenerate the keys, i cant copy the pub key to the remote-server as I get "permission denied again".

Comment: Unless you are planning to run jenkins as root, testing your script through the terminal as root is a useless test. You need to run your script as the jenkins user. To allow the jenkins user to access the remote machine without a password, you need to run those steps mentioned above. If you already have a key, try running `ssh-add` as the jenkins user after copying the key to the jenkins user's ssh folder.